# Create an errorbar for every point of a plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataset below:

```
ww_long<-structure(list(Group = c("OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", 
"OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "SHAM", "SHAM", 
"SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", 
"SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", 
"Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", 
"Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling"), Weeks = c(9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21), Weights = c(19.6166666666667, 21.5916666666667, 22.2666666666667, 
22.25, 22.4, 23.2, 23.6166666666667, 24.6166666666667, 26.3583333333333, 
27.025, 27.9833333333333, 28.7916666666667, 28.975, 18.9666666666667, 
19.2916666666667, 19.3666666666667, 19.2166666666667, 19.8583333333333, 
19.8083333333333, 20.525, 21.3416666666667, 21.5333333333333, 
21.5583333333333, 21.8666666666667, 22.0916666666667, 22.0416666666667, 
19.4225, 19.7025, 19.7225, 19.5775, 20.1275, 20.1325, 20.29, 
21.065, 21.5325, 21.4375, 21.63, 21.6175, 21.875)), row.names = c(NA, 
-39L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and with the code below I create this plot but my problem is that for every week my error bars seem to be the same while I different error bar for every week. They all have the same lenth.

```
ggplot(ww_long, aes(x = as.numeric(Weeks), y = Weights, group = Group, color = Group)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Weights - sd(Weights), ymax = Weights + sd(Weights)), width = 0.2, size = 1) +
  labs(title = "Weekly Weights", x = "Age (Weeks)", y = "Weights (g)", color = "Group") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(names(ww)[-1]), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(16, 32, by = 2), expand = c(0, 0), labels = function(x) round(x)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(16, 32))
```

I create

[image]

Comment: the different groups are defined by different color so lets say that I need one ymin and one ymax as new columns in my ww_long dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that all of the `Weights` data is being used in the `sd` calculation which makes the error bars the same. You could break your data into groups, calculate the `sd`, then combine them to make your plot. However, the most efficient way would be to use `group_by(Group)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ww_long<-structure(list(Group = c("OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", 
                                  "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "SHAM", "SHAM", 
                                  "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", 
                                  "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", 
                                  "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", 
                                  "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling"), Weeks = c(9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
                                                                              14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
                                                                              17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
                                                                              20, 21), Weights = c(19.6166666666667, 21.5916666666667, 22.2666666666667, 
                                                                                                   22.25, 22.4, 23.2, 23.6166666666667, 24.6166666666667, 26.3583333333333, 
                                                                                                   27.025, 27.9833333333333, 28.7916666666667, 28.975, 18.9666666666667, 
                                                                                                   19.2916666666667, 19.3666666666667, 19.2166666666667, 19.8583333333333, 
                                                                                                   19.8083333333333, 20.525, 21.3416666666667, 21.5333333333333, 
                                                                                                   21.5583333333333, 21.8666666666667, 22.0916666666667, 22.0416666666667, 
                                                                                                   19.4225, 19.7025, 19.7225, 19.5775, 20.1275, 20.1325, 20.29, 
                                                                                                   21.065, 21.5325, 21.4375, 21.63, 21.6175, 21.875)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                     -39L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dat <- ww_long %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(upper = Weights + sd(Weights),
         lower = Weights - sd(Weights)) %>%
  ungroup()

dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Weeks), y = Weights, group = Group, color = Group)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, width = 0.2), linewidth = 1) +
  labs(title = "Weekly Weights", x = "Age (Weeks)", y = "Weights (g)", color = "Group") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(9,21,1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(16, 32, by = 2), expand = c(0, 0), labels = function(x) round(x)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(16, 32))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

OLD ANSWER:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ww_long<-structure(list(Group = c("OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", 
                                  "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "OVX", "SHAM", "SHAM", 
                                  "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", 
                                  "SHAM", "SHAM", "SHAM", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", 
                                  "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling", 
                                  "Cycling", "Cycling", "Cycling"), Weeks = c(9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
                                                                              14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
                                                                              17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
                                                                              20, 21), Weights = c(19.6166666666667, 21.5916666666667, 22.2666666666667, 
                                                                                                   22.25, 22.4, 23.2, 23.6166666666667, 24.6166666666667, 26.3583333333333, 
                                                                                                   27.025, 27.9833333333333, 28.7916666666667, 28.975, 18.9666666666667, 
                                                                                                   19.2916666666667, 19.3666666666667, 19.2166666666667, 19.8583333333333, 
                                                                                                   19.8083333333333, 20.525, 21.3416666666667, 21.5333333333333, 
                                                                                                   21.5583333333333, 21.8666666666667, 22.0916666666667, 22.0416666666667, 
                                                                                                   19.4225, 19.7025, 19.7225, 19.5775, 20.1275, 20.1325, 20.29, 
                                                                                                   21.065, 21.5325, 21.4375, 21.63, 21.6175, 21.875)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                     -39L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
ovx <- ww_long %>%
  filter(Group == 'OVX') %>%
  mutate(upper = Weights + sd(Weights),
         lower = Weights - sd(Weights))

sham <- ww_long %>%
  filter(Group == 'SHAM') %>%
  mutate(upper = Weights + sd(Weights),
         lower = Weights - sd(Weights))

cyc <- ww_long %>%
  filter(Group == 'Cycling') %>%
  mutate(upper = Weights + sd(Weights),
         lower = Weights - sd(Weights))

comb <- rbind(ovx, sham)
comb <- rbind(comb, cyc)

comb %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Weeks), y = Weights, group = Group, color = Group)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, width = 0.2), linewidth = 1) +
  labs(title = "Weekly Weights", x = "Age (Weeks)", y = "Weights (g)", color = "Group") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(9,21,1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(16, 32, by = 2), expand = c(0, 0), labels = function(x) round(x)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(16, 32))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>